# how can i provide string array like [899,900,009] as input parameters in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter for one of our project for load testing. 
How to pass a String[] like [Joy,Roy,Murali] as input parameters in Jmeter

Comment: Is this a parameter for a restful service, a web service, a jms queue or topic? Where do you need it?

Comment: I have got the solution. We can pass multiple values on the same variable name again and again, same as hidden variables logic

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution. We can pass multiple values on the same variable name again and again, same as hidden variables logic

```
<elementProp name="column5" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                  <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.value">0.0</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                  <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.name">column5</stringProp>
                </elementProp>

                <elementProp name="column5" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                  <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.value">0.0</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                  <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.name">column5</stringProp>
                </elementProp>

                <elementProp name="column5" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                  <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.value">0.0</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                  <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                  <stringProp name="Argument.name">column5</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
```

and then we can read it as String[] column5 in for formbeans